# FormulaR1C1 #NAME error

Tags: excel, vba

I've started learning VBA for my exam and whenever I ran this code, instead of the SUMs at the end of the row I got #NAME error. If I click on it and refresh, it calculates it as intended.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

(SZUM instead of SUM because of the language settings)

```
 Sub RandomDice()

 Const min = 2
 Const max = 10
 Dim c As Integer, r As Integer


 'Random between 2 and 10 for the column and row numbers     
 c = Int(Rnd() * (max - min + 1)) + 1
 r = Int(Rnd() * (max - min + 1)) + 1


'Clear the content with max+1 size range     
 Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(max + 1, max + 1)).Clear


'Filling the cells with numbers between 1 and 6     
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
 For i = 1 To r
   For j = 1 To c
     Cells(i, j) = Int(6 * Rnd() + 1)
   Next j
 Next i


'Calculate the SUM for each row
Cells(1, c + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SZUM(RC[-" + Trim(Str(c)) + "]:RC[-1])"
Cells(1, c + 1).Copy
Range(Cells(1, c + 1), Cells(r, c + 1)).PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Uhr.png)

Comment: SZUM is not a valid VBA function. If I change the code to "=SUM(RC..." it works fine.

Comment: change `+ Trim(Str(c)) +` to `& c &`.  use `&` for concatenation not `+`

Comment: Confirmed that changing from `SZUM` to `SUM` works as intended using Excel 2013 set to english. Can you try recording a macro of you placing a SUM formula in a cell and review how the code is generated?

Comment: Yeah it was the 'SZUM'. I thought I had to use language specific one. Thanks for the help. I didn't even think that it was a problem because it calculated it after refresh.
I'll use & from now on too.

Comment: Try `FormulaR1C1Local` with SZUM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA is very EN-US centric and expects the english function names as well as commas for a list separator regardless of what your system's regional settings use (e.g. `;` ) or what language your Office installation is in.

To use the formulas as they would appear on your worksheet, use either the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) or [Range.FormulaR1C1Local property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838568.aspx).

```
'in HU-HU¹
Cells(1, c + 1).FormulaR1C1Local = "=SZUM(RC[-" + Trim(Str(c)) + "]:RC[-1])"
'or in EN-US,
Cells(1, c + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-" + Trim(Str(c)) + "]:RC[-1])"
```

For `xlA1` syntax the equivalent properties are [Range.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)  and 
[Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx).

---

¹<sub>[SZUM függvény](https://support.office.com/hu-hu/article/SZUM-f%C3%BCggv%C3%A9ny-043E1C7D-7726-4E80-8F32-07B23E057F89)</sub>

Comment: Some good info here. I didn't know, and I've been using Excel and VBA for a long time.